# ERR! 403 when trying to publish a package to npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to publish a package to npm. You can see the repository here: https://github.com/biowaffeln/mdx-state

I logged in to npm with `npm login`, then I ran `npm publish` and got the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/mdx-state - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check for potential security issues by executing `npm audit`?

Comment: Yes I did, it said 0 security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. Apparently, I didn't **verify my email address**, so that's why I didn't have the permission to upload packages. Talk about an unhelpful error message!

Comment: How did you verify it ?

Comment: Check your inbox, you should have an email from npm asking you to click on a link

Answer (score 0):

Login to npm website, Under your profile image in nav section, go to access tokens and delete already existing access tokens if any.

Now try logging in from the terminal and see if it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Just resend a new email to verify the email address and everything works.