# Various issues when publishing npm package

Tags: npm

when following the [guide](https://zellwk.com/blog/publish-to-npm/) I try to publish with `npm publish` and then I get the error

```
npm notice
npm notice   <NAME>@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 0B   index.d.ts
npm notice 300B package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          <NAME>
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      <NAME>-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  326 B
npm notice unpacked size: 300 B
npm notice shasum:        f736904e1898979ee092c84953b96a5b4d79bf48
npm notice integrity:     sha512-r+lqbZVF+iQUY[...]+OPxw0CAP5LcA==
npm notice total files:   2
npm notice
npm ERR! code E402
npm ERR! 402 Payment Required - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/<NAME> - You must sign up for private packages
```

and following the article and doing `npm publish --access public` I get the error

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/<NAME> - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

with the error [I have verified my email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705901/err-403-when-trying-to-publish-a-package-to-npm)

npm version: `7.6.0`
I have ensured I am logged into the correct username with `npm login` and `npm whoami`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the package is scoped properly. I was running into this because I had .com at the end of our company name before the /package-name.

Example: "@ideadesignmedia.com/package" should be "@ideadesignmedia/package"